# Write values in string array in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    char a[1000][30];
    int nr = 0;
    char temp[30];

    printf ("Nr  magaz: ");
    scanf ("%d", &nr);

    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        printf("Magazin nr: %d", &i);
        do {
            scanf("%[^\n]s", temp);
        }
        while (temp == !"\0");
        printf("\n");
        strcpy(a[i],temp);
    }
    printf("%s",a[0]);
    return 1;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/BkHXPSlCZ

I want to store some values in a matrix and print them but I have wrong values at the output
First, enter how many values will keep my matrix, then enter each value separately. 
 But in part 2 it is not possible to introduce these values and program prints random numbers

Comment: `while (temp == !"\0");`  ??

Comment: to check if string is empty or no

Comment: Do not compare strings with the equal operator `==`, use `strcmp`. But in this case you can just compare the first character of the string: `temp[0] != '\0'`

Comment: `"%[^\n]"` does *not* skip leading whitespace like `%s` does... add a space before the *format specifier*, e.g. `" %[^\n]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of issues leading to *Undefined Behavior*, and your funny numbers come from attempting to print the address of `i` (e.g. `&i`) as a decimal integer value with `"%d"`.

Before getting to the corrections, let's start with some basics. If you need constants (e.g. `30` or `1000`), then `#declare MAXC 30` for max characters and do the same `#declare MAXL 1000` for max lines or use an `enum` to do both at once, e.g.

```
enum { MAXC = 30, MAXL = 1000 };    /* declare constants */
```

That way if you need to adjust the values, you have one single and convenient location at the top of your source to do it -- without picking though all declarations, loop variables, etc.. to make the changes.

It is also a good idea to initialize your arrays you intend to use for storing strings, to avoid an inadvertent failure to *nul-terminate*, e.g.

```
    char a[MAXL][MAXC] = {""};
    char temp[MAXC] = "";
```

(it's a good idea to initialize all variables)

Next, the most important thing you can ever do to protect against *Undefined Behavior* is to ***validate all user input*** (all input actually). If you do not validate you actually receive the input you were expecting, and that the value received is within the range that is usable by your program, you can have no confidence that you will not invoke undefined behavior on the next statement that uses that input (for all you know a cat could be stepping on the keyboard). To validate the input, always check the **return** of the input function and then validate the value falls within the needed range, e.g.

```
    printf ("Introdu nr. magazine vizitate (1-1000): ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &nr) != 1) {   /* validate ALL user input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;   /* returning 1 to shell indicates EXIT_FAILURE */
    }
    if (nr < 1 || nr > 1000) {   /* validate nr in range */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: value out of range.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

You don't need a `do ... while (...)` in addition to your `for` to take input and fill `a`. You can simply do it all with your `for` loop, e.g.

```
    /* prompt, get input, validate, copy temp to 'a' */
    for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
        printf ("Magazin nr [%2d]: ", i);
        /* protect against buffer overrun with field-width */
        if (scanf(" %29[^\n]", temp) != 1) {  /* catch EOF */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: user canceled input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy (a[i],temp);
    }
```

(You did make a smart decision in reading to `temp` before copying to your array to allow separate validation before the copy.)

**note:** how a `space` was left before the `%` to consume the leading whitepace (e.g. the `'\n'` left from pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> from the entry of `nr`) and how the *field-width* modifier to the `%[..]` format specifier is used to limit input to no more than `29` characters (saving room for the *nul-terminating* character) to insure your input will actually fit in `a[i]`, e.g.

```
 scanf(" %29[^\n]", temp)
```

With all values now safely stored in `a`, you can use them at will, or simply output them with:

```
    /* output stored strings in 'a' */
    for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
        printf ("a[%2d] : '%s'\n", i, a[i]);
```

Putting it altogether, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 30, MAXL = 1000 };    /* declare constants */

int main (void) 
{
    char a[MAXL][MAXC] = {""};
    char temp[MAXC] = "";
    int nr = 0;

    printf ("Introdu nr. magazine vizitate (1-1000): ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &nr) != 1) {   /* validate ALL user input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;   /* returning 1 to shell indicates EXIT_FAILURE */
    }
    if (nr < 1 || nr > 1000) {   /* validate nr in range */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: value out of range.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* prompt, get input, validate, copy temp to 'a' */
    for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
        printf ("Magazin nr [%2d]: ", i);
        /* protect against buffer overrun with field-width */
        if (scanf(" %29[^\n]", temp) != 1) {  /* catch EOF */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: user canceled input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy (a[i],temp);
    }

    /* output stored strings in 'a' */
    for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
        printf ("a[%2d] : '%s'\n", i, a[i]);

    return 0;   /* returning 0 indicates EXIT_SUCCESS */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanfstring
Introdu nr. magazine vizitate (1-1000): 5
Magazin nr [ 0]: My favorite
Magazin nr [ 1]: magazine is
Magazin nr [ 2]: one with good
Magazin nr [ 3]: articles and
Magazin nr [ 4]: commentary.
a[ 0] : 'My favorite'
a[ 1] : 'magazine is'
a[ 2] : 'one with good'
a[ 3] : 'articles and'
a[ 4] : 'commentary.'
```

Handling errors:

```
$ ./bin/scanfstring
Introdu nr. magazine vizitate (1-1000): ten
error: invalid input.

$ ./bin/scanfstring
Introdu nr. magazine vizitate (1-1000): 1001
error: value out of range.
```

That said, `scanf` contains many pitfalls just waiting to trap new (and not so new) C programmers. When taking user input a *line-oriented* function like `fgets` or POSIX `getline` are much less prone to causing subtle errors (you just need to remember to trim the trailing `'\n'` included by each in the buffer they fill).

You have one additional circumstance to protect against. What if the user enters more than `29` characters for a string? As it is, `scanf` will read `29` and leave the rest in the *input buffer* (`stdin`). The result will be that the remaining characters will be read as part of the next input. The can cause an *matching failure* if the next input is an integer or floating-point value. To protect against a user entering more than will fit, you will need a way to check that you have read the entire string.

With `scanf` you lack an easy way to confirm you have read an entire line of input. You can always simply discard any remaining characters reading with `getchar()` until the `'\n'` or `EOF` is reached, but that too has problems. With `fgets` or `getline`, you simply check that the final character read was a `'\n'`. If it wasn't, you know additional characters remain unread. That is just one of the advantages of using *line-oriented* input functions.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Set number of values to stock: ok
enter each velue separately: ok
is that what you wanted to do?

```
 int main (void)
{
  char a[1000][30];
  int nr = 0;
  char temp[30];

  printf ("Introdu nr. magazine vizitate: ");
  scanf ("%d", &nr);

  for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
      printf ("Magazin nr: %d\n", i);
      scanf ("%s", &temp); //fill a temporary array
      strcpy (a[i], temp); //copy the content of the array into the tab of array
      printf ("temp:%s ||| a[i]:%s\n", temp, a[i]);
    }
  printf ("%s\n", a[0]);
  return (0);
}
```

I tried to modify your actual code the less possible.

Comment: In the statement `scanf ("%s", &temp)` -> `&` is not required when taking the string as input. `temp` decays to the base address of the array.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your program.

First:

```
printf("Magazin nr: %d", &i);
```

`printf` don't need `&` with the variable. Change it to:

```
printf("Magazin nr: %d", i);
```

Second:

```
while (temp == !"\0");
```

You don't need a loop to take a string as input using `scanf`.

Third:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", temp);
```

This `scanf` will consume the newline character left in input buffer because of previous `scanf`. Change this to:

```
scanf("% [^\n]s", temp);
```

With these change, program will look like:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a[1000][30];
    int nr = 0;
    char temp[30];

    printf ("Introdu nr. magazine vizitate: ");
    scanf ("%d", &nr);

    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", temp);
        printf("Magazin nr: %d\n", i);
        strcpy(a[i],temp);
    }
    //printing strings
    for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**One suggestion** - it's better to use `fgets` instead of `scanf` for the string input.